# How to write Kafka connector to integrate with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to write a **Kafka connector** to fetch data from the facebook. The problems are,

1. How to fetch data from facebook through their API without exceeding the limit of API hit provided by facebook? The connector should call facebook API for data after a specific time interval so that the number of hits won't exceed.
2. Each user can hit the facebook API with their Access Token so users can't share the same topic partition. So how to handle this scenario. Do we have to create one partition for each user?

I read a few guides and blogs to understand Kafka connect and write a connector.

**Confluent**- https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html

**Kafka Documentation**- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Conceptually It gave me an idea about what is Kafka connect, how it works and what are the important classes to write a Kafka connector. But still, I am confused that practically how to write and run a connector. I tried to find step by step development guide but didn't get.

Any tutorial or pdf If you could suggest which have detailed step by step development guide to write and run Kafka connector.

Answer (score 0):

The only "official guide" is in those links you have

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#developing-a-simple-connector

I personally have no experience with the Facebook API, but I assume it uses REST, so you could make start by forking the [kafka-connect-rest](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest) project, but the simplest answer to not exceed the limit would be to not send more requests than you are allowed within a given time period ([add a timer to the code that waits between requests](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest/blob/master/kafka-connect-rest-plugin/src/main/java/com/tm/kafka/connect/rest/RestSourceConnectorConfig.java#L32-L35))

Also, one connector would only have one set of access keys. How you create the `ConnectRecord` objects to ultimately partition the records is up to you, but I don't think having an access key per user will scale very well. It might make more sense to have one key tied to one application, then each user will accept that that application has access to read certain details from their account.